# Dynamically disable inputs in react component with multiple instances

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm in the situation where a small form (`AddPersonFormComponent`) is added to the main component on a button click with the possibility of having multiple Persons.

I've implemented this but on `PersonForm` submit i need to disable the inputs of the `PersonForm`.
At the moment I'm doing this by manually disabling all inputs:

```
function disableInputs() {
    document.getElementById('personName').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('personAdress').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('personPhone').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('personEmail').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('personJob').disabled = true;
}
```

The problem with this is that when I have multiple Persons in the page, it disables inputs just for the first form and not the others. 
Is there a better way to do this so this bug doesn't occur?

Comment: Can you share `AddPersonFormComponent` and `PersonForm`?

Answer (score 0):

You should follow this pattern

```
const InputComponent = ({ isDisabled }) => {
  return <input disabled={isDisabled} />;
};
class FormComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <InputComponent isDisabled={this.props.isDisabled} />;
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem with my situation is that i have multiple instances of the child component. So if i follow the presented pattern, it will disable all the inputs at once even though i want to disable them individually.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using ids'. By definition id is a `unique identifier`, it is supposed to be in DOM only once.

So `getElementById` will always return only the first element with given id. You should use class instead if you want to manipulate all the copies.

^ That's the clarification for why only first form is getting disabled

But when you are using react, it's better you do the things in react way as mentioned in Ricky's answer, you can pass a boolean variable to all inputs and setting that boolean to false will disable all the inputs